# How to pass props to a children object? children will only have a button or a text

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, ecmascript-6, jsx

```
export const PopOver = ({
  children, -----------------------------------------> I get children
  headerText,
  bodyText,
  hasHeader,
  hasBody,
  hasFooter,
  cancelButtonText,
  okButtonText,
  hasCloseButton,
  onOkPress,
  onCancelPress,
  ...rest
}: PopoverProps): JSX.Element => {
  return (
    <Popover
      trigger={(triggerProps) => {
        return <Button {...triggerProps}>Trigger</Button>; //How do I pass trigger props to the children I get???
      }}
      {...rest}
    >
```

In the code I have mentioned above, I want to return children (this.props.children) instead of the button to make it more generic. something to the equivalent of:

```
return (
    <Popover
      trigger={(triggerProps) => {
        return <child {...triggerProps}>Trigger</child>;
      }}
      {...rest}
    >
```

Comment: What are ``triggerProps`` and what ``children`` are expected? Can you provide more details on ``Popover``

Comment: This comes from the native base library! Button or text or whatever child we pass is an actual trigger that invokes a popup and it's own props are triggerprops.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<Popover
  trigger={triggerProps => 
    React.Children.map(children, child =>
      React.isValidElement(child) 
        ? React.cloneElement(child, { ...triggerProps }) 
        : child
    )
  }
  {...rest}
/>
```

References:

https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactchildren

https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#cloneelement